# Template argument deduction and unification

Tags: c++, templates, programming-languages

```
template<typename T>
void f1(T t);

template<typename T>
void f2(const T t);


template<typename T>
void f3(T& t);

template<typename T>
void f4(const T& t);


template<typename T>
void f5(T&& t);  //universal reference

template<typename T>
void f6(const T&& t);
```

what's the difference in these six kinds function template?

what's the relationship between Template argument deduction and Unification(a general PLT concept)?

===
comment:

I know to get some details from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction. But this website is still confused. Maybe a little more clear description is helpfull about dealing with process of Template argument deduction.

Comment: Time spent watching [Scott's presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11) would be well spent. Dare I say the majority of your questions would likely be covered.

Comment: `f1` and `f2` are same declaration (that `const` only constraint in body definition).

Comment: what do you mean by " Unification(a general PLT concept)"?

Comment: I think Template argument deduction is a process that determine template parameters T from A and P. About the meaning of T, A, P, please refer to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction.          The process seems link the unification which commonly is used when write a interepter. so, I add "a general program language theory(PLT) concept". But I'm not sure about it, so I ask here.

Answer (score 0):

For your PLT related question, IMHO, unification deduces the type when a function is *defined*. Argument type is deduced from how the function *itself* use the argument.

A template-argument function is instantiated when it is *used*. The argument type is passed from function *caller*. Then the compiler check whether the argument type is compliant to how argument is used in the function body. This sounds like 'dynamic typing', which might allow more correct code but potentially reject less bad code.

The following C++14 code works. The auto argument type is internally implemented with template.

```
([] (auto f, auto b) {
    return b ? f(string("str")) : MyIntToString(f(MyInt(422)));
})([] (auto x) { return x; }, true)
```

With plain unification, the following Haskell-style code won't pass type checker.

```
(\f b -> if b
         then f 1
         else StringToNumber(f "123")) (\x -> x) True
```

'f' is expected to be both 'Int->t1' and 'String->t2', which does not unify.

Hindley-Milner won't help either, since it generalizes at 'let' but here is only a lambda argument.

Comment: it can be "Int|String -> t"?